# Amadeus Dated Flight from release 5.4.1

Tags: java, amadeus

Has anyone here worked with the DatedFlight class to retrieve flight status as of Amadeus Java class from version 5.4.1? What issues have you experienced? Is there a list of known issues I can refer to for this Flight Status feature that is recently released?

I have used the DatedFlight class to retrieve scheduled flight information from Amadeus for flight SQ479. However, I do not get consistent results. Sometimes I get ResponseException. Sometimes I get no results. However, when I go to the Amadeus Dev portal and make a call RESTful call from the portal it works. Please see the code example below.

````
        .builder("YOUR_AMADEUS_API_KEY","YOUR_AMADEUS_API_SECRET")
        .build();

    // Returns the status of a given flight
    DatedFlight[] flightStatus = amadeus.schedule.flights.get(Params
        .with("flightNumber", "319")
        .and("carrierCode", "AZ")
        .and("scheduledDepartureDate", "2021-03-13"));

   if (flightStatus[0].getResponse().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        System.out.println("Wrong status code: " + flightStatus[0].getResponse().getStatusCode());
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println(flightStatus[0]);```
````

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this particular scheduling function is only available in Test API. When requesting in production the data part of JSON is empty. But when requested in test it is fully populated.

Clearly I did not read the manual....